# strpos() with string from database in loop

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

So what I have been trying to do is, checking some URLS to see if they have a specific TLD in them. For example:

**

> if foo.edu has .edu in it or not.

**

For this I have a table in my Database with some TLDs added in it such has .gov,.edu etc

What I have been trying to do is create a function which compares the given URL with strings(TLDS) in the database. What I am encountering is kind of strange or maybe I'm just exhausted that I cannot think of anything else. The function should just tell me if it did found any such string(HERE:TLD) in the url but case is different:

strpos_array() is a function I am using for taking arrays in strpos();

Code :

```
public function get_specialTLD(){

    $query = $this->db->select('TLD');
    $query = $this->db->from('foo_tlds');
    $query = $this->db->get();

     return $query->result_array(); //outputs the list of TLDS in the table 
}
```

Should check the URL against each TLD

```
public function specialCheck($site){

    $tlds = $this->get_specialTLD();

    foreach($tlds as $tld){
        $exploded = explode(' ',$tld['TLD']); 
        if($this->strpos_array($site, $exploded)>0){
            echo 'spl';
    }else{
        echo 'no';
    }
}
}
```

Now in this case what this will output is

**no no spl**(if this index(example:.edu) of TLD was found matching).
If I instead try returning boolean instead of echoing, it will obviously just stop at the first instance of the check, that is
if it found no matches, it will return FALSE and for the rest of TLDs will be left without checking with the URL.

What I am suspecting is this is because of just using foreach(), maybe I should be using something else.? or I should stick to hard coded method which uses strstr

```
if ((strstr($site,".gov")) or (strstr($site,".edu")) or (strstr($site,".net"))) )
     {
       echo 'Spl'
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like this?

> public function specialCheck($site){
>
> ```
> $tlds = $this->get_specialTLD();
>
> foreach($tlds as $tld){
>     $exploded = explode(' ',$tld['TLD']); 
>     if($this->strpos_array($site, $exploded)>0){
>         return TRUE;
>     }
>  }
>
>  return FALSE;
> ```
>
> }

In this case, if it finds a match it'll return TRUE otherwise FALSE.

It won't exit until a match has been found or until all TLDs have been checked.

Comment: I think I need some coffee, thank you. I understand that when I tried returning boolean, I put it inside the wrong conditions and in a wrong way(Inside the loop). Sometimes little mistakes cost more than little. Thank you man! ^_^

Comment: Well my answer fixes it equally.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you need to `break`:

```
$found = false;
foreach($tlds as $tld){
    $exploded = explode(' ',$tld['TLD']); 
    if($this->strpos_array($site, $exploded)>0){
        echo 'spl';
        $found = true;
        break;
    }else{
       echo 'no';
    }
}
return $found;
```

Comment: Thing is if I break it, then the other remaining TLDs will go unchecked with the given URL. Breaking is kind of same if I assume I was trying to return Boolean.

Comment: So only break when it is found?

Comment: I have updated the answer to get rid of the break in the else. It will only exit the loop if it finds something or reaches the end.

Comment: Even if you do it like that, it is still going to return the else condition anyways. Perhaps I was doing it wrong: Adding boolean does make it work right, as given in answer by @Dodu , what I did wrong was putting returning boolean in wrong conditions.

Comment: @Arfan I have added how you would return the boolean with the break. You just return once outside of the loop. So it returns either when it has done them all or found a match.

Comment: Yes, that is yet another way of doing it. So what is the difference now, if I just return true or false, instead of doing a break. Because both methods tend to do the same thing now.

Comment: Well in this case, I just think it is better practice to have just 1 return statement at the end of the function instead of 2 or more within it.

Comment: Say in the future, you added more if conditions, you will have to do return statements for each one! Or you would rewrite it to be like this anyway.

Comment: Oh. So what I understand is, this somehow gives me flexibility with the returning statements, If I had to do something else if(xx==yy)... and so on. :)